# Jenkins Groovy Declarative Script fails to publish files to Confluence with 'bad types' error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, confluence

Is anyone able to make sense of this error? This script to publish files to Confluence during Jenkins jobs was working just fine as recently as a week ago. Now it is throwing errors and my googling hasn't been able to reveal what it's complaining about.

The code (Groovy in a declarative script):

```
publishConfluence siteName: '', spaceName: '', pageName: '', buildIfUnstable: true, fileSet: 'text.html'
```

And the error:

```
[confluence] Uploading attachments to Confluence page: www.example.com
[confluence] Evaluating fileset pattern: text.html
[confluence] Found 2 workspace artifact(s) to upload to Confluence...
[confluence] Uploading 2 file(s) to Confluence...
[confluence]  - Uploading file: text.html (text/html)
ERROR: Unable to upload file...
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class com.atlassian.confluence.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteAttachment -&gt; long)
```

e: Confluence version is 7.4.8 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin just needed an upgrade to match the Confluence version.